# Qual a diferença entre lista inversa (inverted index) e lista reversa (reverse index)?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, índices

Qual o conceito, as características, as vantagens e desvantagens e um exemplo de utilização (aplicação).

Comment: Agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Índice reverso

Até onde eu entendo, é apenas o índice com classificação ao contrário do que seja natural, ou seja, do maior para o menor.

Posso estar enganado por falta de um contexto maior onde o termo está sendo usado.

Ele é usado quando precisa justamente essa característica. Ele não tem nada de especial na sua estrutura, apenas o dado é tratado diferente (o número, de qualquer tipo, é negativado e a *string* sofre uma pequena manipulação nos seus caracteres de acordo com o *collate*).

## Índice invertido

Se entendi o que está na pergunta, é um índice onde você tem vários valores apontados, que não é o normal.

Isso é muito usado em busca textual, então você procura por palavras, o índice acha a palavra e lá tem todos os locais onde a palavra está contida.

Em alguns casos o índice pode ter mais informações para melhorar a busca, como colocar local onde a informação está, peso dela, etc.

Ele é invertido porque é mais comum várias chaves apontarem para um dado concreto ou até que seja um para um.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).