# Existe alguma diferença no desempenho dependendo do que se busca?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, desempenho

Existe alguma diferença no desempenho ao consultar no banco de dados, dependendo da quantidade de caracteres informados na consulta?

Por exemplo, se for feito uma consulta por qualquer registro que possua o caractere 'a', vai gastar mais processamento do que buscar por uma palavra maior, exemplo "teste"?

Estou com essa dúvida, pois atualmente os clientes digitando apenas uma letra já pode realizar a consulta, caso isso impacte no tempo de resposta, penso em por um limite mínimo de dígitos.

Estou usando PostgreSQL.

Comment: Você diz procurar por em `a` em qualquer lugar ou `a` só no começo?

Comment: @bigown em qualquer lugar, qualquer registro que possua o caractere `a`

Comment: Sim a busca pela segunda letra só começa após a primeira encontrada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A busca em si é para dar uma diferença próxima de zero. Claro que uma análise de mais caracteres pode fazer a busca ser um pouco mais lenta, mas isso é quase teórico, porque o grosso do trabalho de busca não é a comparação dos caracteres. Eu diria que a diferença deve ser inferior a 0,1%.

Só que procurar uma única letra deve gerar uma quantidade imensa de resultados, e terá que transmitir (em vários níveis) tudo isso, óbvio que transmitir mais informação demorará mais. Então por motivos indiretos procurar um caractere pode ser um pouco, ou até bem mais lento no resultado final, a não ser que não ache algo, o que é improvável.

O maior problema é poder buscar em qualquer lugar. Isso impede o uso de um [índice normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101). Aí não faz muita diferença se está buscando um ou um monte de caracteres juntos. Mas não pense que será uma tragédia por fazer assim.

Na verdade cabe a recomendação de sempre: teste no seu caso.

Se achar que não ficou bom talvez seja o caso de usar um [índice invertido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169055/101), também chamado de [*full text index*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search). O [PostgreSQL tem esse recurso](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html), mas não posso garantir que seja útil para seu caso. Nem sempre o ganho é grande.

Se estiver usando um cliente web ou algo do tipo é possível que a latência da rede e processamento intermediário afete mais que o acesso ao banco de dados. Principalmente se os acessos forem interativos ao banco de dados (cada caractere digitado faz uma busca). Aí funciona melhor localmente, se possível em bancos de dados embarcados na aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

O desempenho do resultado da busca vai depender da quantidade de registros que a mesma irá retornar. Por exemplo, se quer apenas registros que possuem a palavra `amor` e se há 1000 registros que começam com a letra `a` e há apenas 100 que começam com a palavra `amor`, então logicamente se você buscar por apenas a letra `a` irá demorar mais, pois retornará os 1000 registros ao invés de 100.

Answer (score -1):

Depende da quantidade de informação registrada. Se você permitir a procura por apenas um registro, 'a' digamos, que é muito comum, em um banco de dados de tamanho considerável, o retorno poderá ser um número excessivo de registros. Caso a sua intenção seja agilizar a vida do usuário mostrando o quanto antes resultados para que a interação seja mais responsiva, sugiro utilizar paginação. Assim digitando apenas um caractere, apenas os 10, 20 ou o número que você configurar de resultados iniciais será apresentado. Assim que o usuário informar o restante da palavra, a busca irá se tornar mais específica. Utilize as opções `OFFSET e LIMIT`: ao invés de `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%a%` que pode retornar milhares de linhas, experimente `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%a% LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0` que sempre retornará no máximo 100 resultados.