# Qual a diferença entre Full Text Search e LIKE?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, operador-like, full-text

Tenho ouvido falar bastante no termo *Full Text Search* (FTS) ultimamente, e me disseram que eu deveria usar isso em vez de elaborar as consultas com `LIKE`. Mas como usar o *Full Text Search*? Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens? E quando é realmente melhor usar o FTS em vez de usar o tradicional e simples `LIKE`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`LIKE` normalmente é um mecanismo simples para ser usado em expressões comparando com textos diversos no banco de dados, então ele lê os dados necessários na expressão e aplica o `LIKE` que é uma forma simplificada de [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185301/101).

O FTS é um mecanismo próprio de [indexação invertida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169055/101) de dados do banco. Tecnicamente todo o banco de dados pode ser alvo desta indexação. As chaves neste caso passam ser palavras e elas apontam para todos locais (que foram considerados no índice) onde aparecem estas palavras. Nos mais sofisticados pode haver controle de relevância, proximidade, palavra parcial, contexto, etc.

O FTS costuma ser mais rápido e mais preciso na maioria dos casos, além de ser mais poderoso, mas tem um consumo de espaço para manter as estruturas de índices. O `LIKE` pode ser tão ou mais rápido que o FTS em alguns casos. Há casos onde o `LIKE`pode não ser tão rápido, mas é rápido o suficiente.

Cada banco de dados costuma ter um FTS bem diferente do outro enquanto que o `LIKE` é mais ou menos padrão.

`LIKE` no SQLite:

```
SELECT FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE 'teste%' //costuma ser eficiente com índice apropriado
SELECT FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE '%teste%' //qualquer coisa que tenha 'teste' no meio
SELECT FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE '%teste' //termina com teste
SELECT FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE 'teste_' //termina com um e apenas um caractere qq
SELECT FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE '_teste_' //teste no meio de 1 caractere na ponta
```

FTS no SQLIte:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tabela USING fts3 (col1, col2, text );
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES ('3', 'testo', 'Este é um exemplo');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES ('24', 'exemplo', 'Ok, está bom assim');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES ('13', 'outro', 'Finalizando');
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE tabela MATCH "exemplo"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/LikeXFts.sql).

Answer (score 6):

*LIKE* é usado para pesquisa de seqüência de caracteres em qualquer seqüência de caracteres campos. Este campo pode ser char, varchar, texto, etc. 
Sempre que pesquisamos o banco de dados usando o operador *LIKE*, ele carrega cada linha do banco de dados para comparação. 
Em seguida, descartar as linhas que não correspondem aos critérios dados. Isso usa muita memória e tempo para a execução de consulta.
Como operação é apenas preferido para banco de dados pequeno com poucas linhas.

No caso de pesquisa de texto *FULL TEXT SEARCH* usa INDEXES para pesquisa. Nesse caso, a pesquisa ocorre na tabela de índices. 
Usa menos recursos para execução de consulta mas usa mais espaço para criar ÍNDICES.

Outra diferença é que o *LIKE* não é maleavel e retorna apenas os itens que correspondem 100% enquanto o *FULL TEXT SEARCH* oferece um controle melhor
e pode trazer inclusive os registros próximos àqueles de seu filtro.

Answer (score 4):

*Full Text Search* é uma técnica que se utiliza da indexação das palavras dentro de um campo de texto, permitindo assim fazer a pesquisa rapidamente através de muitos registros. Já o *LIKE* faz uma busca através da sequência de caracteres dentro do campo, ou seja, comparando os textos letra por letra.

*FTS* é mais complexo, e exige uma preparação do gerenciador de banco de dados antes de poder ser utilizado. Já o *LIKE* faz parte do próprio SQL, e só precisa fazer parte da consulta.

Portanto, decidir qual dos dois utilizar depende do propósito do seu sistema e da sua estrutura de banco de dados. Se é interessante para o seu sistema que o usuário possa fazer buscas mais rapidamente e obter resultados próximos daquilo que ele está buscando, o *FTS* é mais recomendado. Se uma busca exata da palavra é suficiente para você, o *LIKE* pode fazer o trabalho.