# Qual real diferença entre o operador '=' e LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, operadores, operador-like

Fazendo outro teste (rs) em uma base de dados que tenho em MySQL, percebi que:

```
SELECT * From client WHERE uuid = '1kvsg4oracxq'
```

retornou o mesmo resultado que:

```
SELECT * From client WHERE uuid LIKE '1kvsg4oracxq'
```

Qual é exatamente a real diferença entre o operador `=` e `LIKE`? Em qual situação é preferencial usar um ou outro?

Comment: Rela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191573/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O igual `=` procura por equivalência caractere por caractere, tem que ser exatamente igual.

Já o `LIKE` procura "algo como", ou seja, conteúdo que tenha o texto procurado em uma parte de onde (coluna(s)) que está procurando. Em geral usa-se o símbolo `%` para indicar onde pode ter caracteres coringa, onde pode ter quaisquer outras coisas.

O uso de '1kvsg4oracxq%' ainda costuma permitir o uso de um índice, mas em qualquer outro lugar ele pode inviabilizar o consumo indexado e ter performance ruim, ou até trágica (depende, tem que medir, nem sempre é ruim). Nesses casos usar um [índice invertido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169055/101) para [*full text search*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191573/101) pode ser mais adequado.

O `_` também é usado para apenas um caractere coringa. Algumas sintaxes permitem outras formas de expressar o que pode usar.

Sem o `%` o resultado é para ser o mesmo. Mas tem uma exceção, que é sobre os espaços no final. O `=` normalmente os ignora. Se não usar `%` no `LIKE`, eles não serão ignorados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).