# Como faço uma busca por uma string em um tabela no Android?

Tags: android, query

Quero pesquisar utilizando o campo "clas", que é uma String. E listPesquisar recebe uma String.

```
    public Cursor listPesquisar(String pesquisa) {
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] fields = new String[]{"_id", "nome", "peso", "altura", "cep", "telefone", "idade", "resultado", "clas"};

        String where = "clas =" + pesquisa;
        db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(DadosDB.NOME_TABELA, fields, where,null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: As respostas abaixo te atente ou precisa de mais alguma informação?!

Answer (score 3):

Se for buscar pela coluna `nome`, pode fazer desta forma usando o operador `=`:

```
cursor = db.query(DadosDB.NOME_TABELA, fields, "nome =?",
            new String[] {"nome"}, null, null, null, null);
```

Mas este caso é se você procura exatamente com o valor da *string* `pesquisa`. Você também pode usar o `LIKE`. Veja essa pergunta sobre [qual diferença entre o operador '=' e LIKE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212220/qual-real-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-operador-e-like).

Como está fazendo uma busca na coluna `clas`, podes fazer desta forma:

```
String where = "clas LIKE '%" + pesquisa + "%'";
cursor = db.query(DadosDB.NOME_TABELA, fields, where, null, null, null, null, null);
```

> [...] o `LIKE` procura "algo como", ou seja, conteúdo que tenha o texto
>   procurado em uma parte de onde (coluna(s)) que está procurando. Em
>   geral usa-se o símbolo % para indicar onde pode ter caracteres
>   coringa, onde pode ter qualquer outras coisa. Maniero

Answer (score 1):

Modifique a linha que usa o parâmetro "pesquisa" dessa forma:

```
String where = "clas like '%" + pesquisa + "%'";
```