# SQL - Como filtrar apenas dominios que contém "hotmail.com";

Tags: sql

Escreva um select que atenda os critérios abaixo:

1° Filtre apenas dominios que contém "hotmail.com";

2° Considere os contratos abaixo; 683679 705126 715651

TABELA

```
SELECT * FROM FDADOS_RE170(3,3) limit 12
carteira; tn; contrato; cpf; tipo_contato; contato; classificacao; origem; score;

3; 1; 710195; 02714662196; Email renilson-stsfatt@hotmail.com; 1 - Excelente; M; 0

3; 1; 710195; 02714662196; Email menbesjanete@uol.com.br ;1 - Excelente M; 0

3; 1; 710195; 02714662196; Email renilson_ca@stsservicos.com.br; 1 - Excelente; M; 0

3; 1; 710195; 02714662196; Email ellen.cristiane123@hotmail.com 1 - Excelente; M; 0

3; 1; 710195; 02714662196; Email mendesjanete@uol.com.br ;9 - Indefinido O; 0

sql
```

Comment: Qual a dúvida então? Qual parte do filtro você não entendeu? Conhece a cláusula `LIKE` de validação?

Comment: Seja bem vindo! Use o operador `like`, ficará assim ... `contato LIKE '%hotmail.com'` Leia esta resposta: [Qual real diferença entre o operador '=' e LIKE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212228/110782)

Comment: Amigo você poderia deixa o código melhor para visualização?

Comment: A duvida é fazer um select que me traga 1° Filtre apenas dominios que contém "hotmail.com";

2° Considere os contratos abaixo; 683679 705126 715651

Comment: Por favor não duplique perguntas. Se a [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400378/112052) não foi bem recebida, concentre seus esforços lá. Edite-a e siga as instruções que foram dadas no comentários, e se ela estiver de acordo será reaberta

Comment: Sem saber o nome da tabela onde iremos trabalhar ficará dificil, os numeros dos contratos  serão inseridos manualmente? Faça: `select * from SUA_TABELA where (contrato = (VARIAVEL_COM_NR_DOS_CONTRATOS)) and contato like '%hotmail.com'`

Comment: Obrigado Luiz Augusto

Comment: Não saber fazer não é dúvida. As dúvidas só surgem após se tentar fazer ou estudar como fazer.

Answer (score -2):

Ficará assim:

```
SELECT * FROM 'TABELA_NOME' 
where 
(contrato = 683679 
OR contrato = 705126 
OR contrato = 715651)
LIKE '%@hotmail.com%'
```

em `TABELA_NOME` é o nome de sua tabela.

Comment: Aceita `lerolero@shotmail.com`, falso positivo para os propósitos da questão

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado verifique novamente o enunciado. Filtre apenas domínios que contêm "hotmail.com". shotmail.com contém hotmail.com, está de acordo com o enunciado. No entanto, lerolero@hotmail.com.br também contém "hotmail.com" e não seria exibido com essa resposta.

Comment: então coloca o '@' e '%' no final, então tudo que tiver @hotmail.com será exibido :'%@hotmail.com%'